# What are the exceptions to the 2nd Derivative Test?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Today in class my professor went over the 2nd derivative rule and was mentioning how there are some exceptions. I wanted to know if anyone I had a more in depth analysis of it. An explanation of what the 2nd Derivative is would also be nice.

Comment: This may depend on what you mean by exceptions. If $f$ is defined in a nieighbourhood of $a$ and twice differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a)=0$ and $f''(a)<0$, then $a$ is a local minimum of $f$ -- without exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, for something to be useful as an actual theorem as opposed to a rule of thumb, there would be conditions to rule out would-be counterexamples (e.g., the fact that $x=1$ maximises $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ is squarely not an exception to 'if $c$ is a local extremum of $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$, if $f'(c)$ exists, and **if $c$ is interior to $A \subset \mathbb{R}$**, then $f'(c)=0$'), so in that sense there are no exceptions.  It would be of little help to say that something is true except when it isn't.

Comment: Perhaps what your professor meant is that sometimes there is a local minimum, but this test won't be able to tell that it's there.

Comment: The second derivative is the derivative of the derivative. If $ g=f'$ then  $g'$ is the 2nd deriv of$ f.$

Comment: Actually, it just occurred to me that what I thought of by the second derivative test might actually be the converse of what most people mean by it.  I invariably get these sorts of things remixed in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x^4$ is a nice example which has the feature that $f''(0) = 0$ even though $x=0$ minimizes $f$. It's not an in depth analysis, i know and i'm sorry. But it serves as a counterexample to the "2nd derivative rule".

For an explanation of the 2nd derivative there is the example where you consider a function $s(t)$, the position (or distance traveled) at time $t$. Then $s'(t)=v(t)$ is the speed and $s''(t)=v'(t)=a(t)$ is the acceleration, i.e the "rate of change of the rate of change of the position" at time $t$. You see how it came twice there?

Comment: Complementarily, $f(x) = -x^4$ and $f(x) = x^3$ both satisfy $f''(0) = 0$, but at $0$ these functions respectively have a minimum and a critical point that is neither a minimum nor a maximum, so all behaviors are possible when $f''(x_0) = 0$---hence, we say that the Second Derivative Test is *indeterminate* in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd derivative tests fails when the polynomial's derivative has a zero with an odd multiplicity greater than one. Ex y' = (x -2)^3, 2 is a local minimum, not an inflection.